# saving a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

I have made some changes to a JSON file in python by using numpy and pandas. I have successfully made the desired changes as I can see through print() function, but I am unable to save the changes as a new file with .json extension. The code is given as below.

```
df = pd.read_json("file_name.json")
result = df.to_json(orient='records')
parsed = json.loads(result)
json_out = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
print(json_out)
```

Comment: We cannot possibly even begin to help you without seeing a [mre] of the code in question. [ask]

Comment: `df.to_json(filename)` will save the dataframe to a JSON file.

Comment: `parsed = json.loads(result)
json_out = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
print(json_out)` these are the last lines of code

Comment: @Khan Code does not belong in comments; please edit your question to include your code in its intended formatting. "*the last lines of code*" also do not constitute a [mre] as proscribed by our guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been better if you had shared the structure of the JSON file with us.

I will work with a hypothetical format in this case:

```
import json

# dummy JSON format
data = {
'employees' : [
    {
        'name' : 'John Doe',
        'department' : 'Marketing',
        'place' : 'Remote'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Jane Doe',
        'department' : 'Software Engineering',
        'place' : 'Remote'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Don Joe',
        'department' : 'Software Engineering',
        'place' : 'Office'
    }
 ]
}

json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

If you format of your JSON is such as above we can save the JSON into a file by:

```
# Directly from the dictionary
with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

# Using a JSON string
with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_string)
```

Reference:

1. https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/